# How can I containerize a monorepo react app that was built with nx

Tags: reactjs, docker, containers, monorepo, nx.dev

I have a monorepo with one react app inside of it, so that I could learn how Nx works. There is no backend to this app. It is a simple todo react app.

The structure is as follows:

```
my-app (root)
├── .idea
├── dist
├── myreactapp
│   ├── .nx
│   └── dist
|   ├── e2e
│   └── src
|   ├── public
│   └── nx.json
└── yarn.lock
└── README.md
└── .gitignore
```

I am able to run

> Nx Run

> Nx Build

> Nx Test

> Nx Serve

all perfectly fine, app is working.

How can I create an image of this monorepo and the app within the monorepo using docker and run the image as a container? I want to be able to add projects to this monorepo in the future and also create new images and containers for the new apps as well.

Will I need Dockerfiles for both the root and for each project? Does having Nx chnage the way I need to write the Dockerfiles? Will I need some sort of compose or .yaml files as well?

I'm new to Docker and am really confused by the Nx project structure.

Comment: Just for my curiosity, what do you mean by _"monorepo"_ here?

Comment: Are you sure you used the right tag with [tag:nomachine-nx]? That is not the same thing as https://nx.dev/

Comment: Sorry yeah I meant to use nx.dev

Comment: @Phil one repository, but many individual projects within that repo